# How To Use Watch/Hot Reloading in Aurelia With Webpack In Visual Studio Project?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have an Aurelia application based off of the [Webpack TypeScript Skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack).

My Aurelia app is inside of a .NET application, inside of a sub controller which renders a main layout template where I include my Aurelia goodness (tag on body and scripts). I want to use the watch/hot reloading capabilities of Webpack, but I am not using the standard `index.html` approach.

What are my options here? Is there a way I can proxy the watcher through to my running application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .NET Core and not the full .NET framework then you can have a look at .NET Core [JavaScript Services](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices). These integrate WebPack in the ASP.NET pipeline.
The samples provided do not include Aurelia however, but I have made a sample based on the mentioned skeleton that works with JavaScript services [here](https://github.com/arjendeblok/skeleton-typescript-webpack-aspnetcore).